# Magento Submit Invoice With Amount Capture Online Not Working

Tags: php, xml, phpmyadmin, magento-1.9, invoice

**When Submitting Invoice With Amount Capture Online**

[image]

**It is showing below error. But it is working with capture offline**

[image]

**Here is the error log:**

> 2015-07-25T11:50:07+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():
>   Entity: line 21: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch:
>   global line 9 and models  in
>   /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php
>   on line 518 2015-07-25T11:50:07+00:00 ERR (3): Warning:
>   simplexml_load_string():           in
>   /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php
>   on line 518 2015-07-25T11:50:07+00:00 ERR (3): Warning:
>   simplexml_load_string():                  ^  in
>   /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php
>   on line 518 2015-07-25T11:50:07+00:00 ERR (3): Warning:
>   simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 22: parser error : Opening and
>   ending tag mismatch: config line 2 and global  in
>   /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php
>   on line 518 2015-07-25T11:50:07+00:00 ERR (3): Warning:
>   simplexml_load_string():       in
>   /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php
>   on line 518 2015-07-25T11:50:07+00:00 ERR (3): Warning:
>   simplexml_load_string():              ^  in
>   /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php
>   on line 518 2015-07-25T11:50:07+00:00 ERR (3): Warning:
>   simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 23: parser error : Extra content
>   at the end of the document  in
>   /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php
>   on line 518 2015-07-25T11:50:07+00:00 ERR (3): Warning:
>   simplexml_load_string():   in
>   /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php
>   on line 518 2015-07-25T11:50:07+00:00 ERR (3): Warning:
>   simplexml_load_string(): ^  in
>   /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php
>   on line 518

Comment: Show us some code and, more importantly, show us the xml request as hinted by `2015-07-25T11:50:07+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 21: parser error : **Opening and ending tag mismatch**: global line 9 and models in `

Comment: how can i show you the xml request ? can you please guide me i am new to magento